# Terraform how to use for_each for ssh_keys when creating multiple digitalocean droplets

Tags: terraform, hcl

**Background**

I am using the [digitalocean_droplet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/droplet) resource. I would like to create multiple digitalocean droplets, each with their own SSH key.

The droplets will be created by reading `locals` variable named `droplets` at the top of the script for ease of modification, and each droplet must have its own SSH key. I am using the [cloudposse/terraform-tls-ssh-key-pair](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-tls-ssh-key-pair) module to create the key pair.

**Problem**

The `digitalocean_droplet` resource requires an array of IDs under the `ssh_keys` key. I know how to provide a single key here, but I am using `for_each` for both the module and for the `digitalocean_ssh_key` resource.

I don't know how to tell the `digitalocean_droplet` resource to, for `ssh_keys`, use multiple values from the `digitalocean_ssh_key` resource.

To use a single key, `ssh_keys` would look like this:

```
ssh_keys = [digitalocean_ssh_key.ssh_key.id]
```

To use multiple, I think that I need to tell `ssh_keys` to "use each of the values generated by the digitalocean_ssh_key resource". But I don't know how to do this.

I expect (and hope) this to simply be a lack of knowledge on HCL.

**What I have tried**

I have tried what I think should be telling `ssh_keys` to use each `.id` from the `digitalocean_ssh_key` resource:

```
ssh_keys = {
  for index, v in digitalocean_ssh_key.ssh_key:
    v => v.id
}
```

However this results in a cycle error on running `terraform plan`:

> Error: Cycle: module.ssh_key_pair.output.private_key (expand), module.ssh_key_pair.var.chmod_command (expand), module.ssh_key_pair.null_resource.chmod, module.ssh_key_pair.output.public_key (expand), module.ssh_key_pair.var.private_key_extension (expand) [etc etc]

I have also tried using `module.ssh_key_pair`, but this does not provide me with an `id`, which is what `ssh_keys` requires.

**Conclusion**

What do I need to do to tell `digitalocean_droplet` to, for each of the configuration in my `locals` variable named "droplets", generate a new SSH key using my module and to assign that SSH key to each individual droplet?

**Code**

```
locals {
  // An example of a single droplet. I will add multiple here in the future.
  droplets = {
    "DROPLET_NAME_AS_KEY" : {
      image = "distro image here"
      size  = "droplet size here"
    }
  }
}

// For each droplet above, create a new digitalocean droplet
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "droplets" {
  for_each = local.droplets
  name     = each.key
  region   = "fra1"
  image    = each.value.image
  size     = each.value.size
  tags     = [each.key]
  // Next is my problem, what goes for ssh_keys??
  ssh_keys = ???
}

// Create a new key pair for each droplet.
module "ssh_key_pair" {
  for_each = digitalocean_droplet.droplets

  source              = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-tls-ssh-key-pair.git?ref=master"
  ssh_public_key_path = "/users/me/.ssh"
  name                = "${each.value.name}"
}

// The link between the key pair resource and the ssh_key for digital ocean.
resource "digitalocean_ssh_key" "ssh_key" {
  for_each = module.ssh_key_pair

  name       = each.value.key_name
  public_key = each.value.public_key
}
```

*Bonus question if the above gets solved:*

I actually use variables for all the values in the `locals` array. These come from environment variables from docker-compose, as I'm running terraform in a container. Is there a simple way to provide an array in docker-compose which can become this array here without me having to update both the `environment` key in docker-compose.yml and this droplets array, and instead just update an array in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I'd probably extend the local variable to have e.g., a name for the SSH key under the `DROPLET_NAME_AS_KEY` and then use the local variable in the SSH resource instead of using resource chaining as that will cause cycle errors you already experienced.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE, I've actually just solved this in a different way. I made the `ssh_key_pair` module also loop `local.droplets`, and in the `ssh_keys` used a for loop to filter `ssh_key` where the key name is the same as the one I'm looping through in the `for_each` in `digitalocean_droplet`.

Comment: But if storing this in the local variable is easier (it is dynamic, and the name for the key is based on the name in locals) - I'll give this a try too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `local.droplets` in all three `for_each` loops to avoid cycles.

You can then access `module.ssh_key_pair` module in `digitalocean_ssh_key` resource with `module.ssh_key_pair[each.key]`.

The `ssh_keys` field in `digitalocean_droplet` resource would be `ssh_keys = [digitalocean_ssh_key.ssh_key[each.key].fingerprint]`.

---

Regarding your bonus question - you could declare this variable:

```
variable "droplets" {
  type = map(object({
    image = string
    size = string
  }))
}
```

And then in `for_each` use `var.droplets` instead of `locals.droplets`.

You can use env variables to set Terraform variables, however:

> For readability, and to avoid the need to worry about shell escaping,
> we recommend always setting complex variable values via variable
> definitions files.

See details here - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables.

Comment: Hey Anton, actually I used `local.droplets` in the `ssh_key_pair` module, and this removed the cycle error I was receiving. Why do I need to also do it in the `digitalocean_ssh_key` resource? For the bonus question, it isn't clear what the key I would provide in docker-compose under `environment` would look like that would work with this variable object map you are suggesting - how would that look?

Comment: @Jimbo it's not a must to use `local.droplets` in `digitalocean_ssh_key` for_each, it's a personal preference, this way it's easier to see that all 3 resources/modules are a part of one thing. About vars - just collapse the map variable into a one-line string. The link I added in the answer has this example for a list var: `export TF_VAR_availability_zone_names='["us-west-1b","us-west-1d"]'`.